# Stripe Problem, please call Stripe ( ) error Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm facing this problem when trying to implement Stripe in my ecommerce

When I put the credit card numbers from Stripe testing website, the website refresh, nothing happens, not even re direct to /success, only this error appears in console:

```
 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Please call Stripe() with your publishable key. 
 You used an empty string.
```

this is my app.js

```
 function App() {

const {isAuthenticated, user} = useSelector((state)=>state.user)

const [stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey] = useState("");

 async function getStripeApiKey() {
 const {data} = await axios.get("/api/v1/stripeapikey");

  setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApiKey)
 }

 useEffect(() => { 

  WebFont.load({
   google:{
     families: [ "Droid Sans", "Chilanka"],
   },
  });

  store.dispatch(loadUser())

  getStripeApiKey()
 }, []);

return (
<Router>
  <Header/>
  {isAuthenticated && <UserOptions user={user} />}
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
    <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails/>}/>
    <Route path="/products" element={<Products/>}/>
    <Route path="/products/:keyword" element={<Products/>}/>
    <Route path="/search" element={<Search/>}/>
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}/>
      <Route path="/account" element={<Profile/>}/>
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}/>
     <Route path="/me/update" element={<UpdateProfile/>}/>
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}/>
     <Route path="/password/update" element={<UpdatePassword/>}/>
    <Route path="/password/forgot" element={<ForgotPassword/>}/> 
    <Route path="/password/reset/:token" element={<ResetPassword/>}/> 
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginSignUp/>}/>
    <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart/>}/>
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}/>
     <Route path="/shipping" element={<Shipping/>}/>
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}/>
     <Route path="/order/confirm" element={<ConfirmOrder/>}/>

     <Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}/>
      <Route  path="/process/payment" element={ <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}><Payment/></Elements>}/>
  </Routes>
<Footer/>
</Router>
 );
}
```

and this is my paymentController, I think the problem may be in the app.js, as how I'm calling StripeP

```
const catchAsyncErrors = require("../middlewares/catchAsyncErrors");

  const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

exports.processPayment = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
const myPayment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
amount: req.body.amount,
currency: "inr",
metadata: {
  company: "Ecommerce",
},
});

res
.status(200)
 .json({ success: true, client_secret: myPayment.client_secret });
 });

exports.sendStripeApiKey = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
res.status(200).json({ stripeApiKey: process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY });
});
```

Comment: In React, the Stripe publishable key is set by calling loadStripe, which you do. However, why do you need to use useState here to set the publishable key? And why are you making a network call? It's just the publishable key (safe and publicly viewable). I think you can just get away with setting it once to a const up top. I also recommend adding debug logs in each block so you can see the current flow of your code and where you're going wrong.

Comment: I'm following a tutorial, maybe it will matter after, but for know what should I remove in order to check if its working? is the useEffect the problem? or the problem is in how I'm using loadStripe/

Answer (score 0):

```
{stripeApiKey && <Route exact path="/process/payment" element={<Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}><Payment/></Elements>}/>}
```

In app.js where you have declared your Payment Route Path just add **and condition**
*&& stripeApiKey*.